# How can I set size of a StringField from Flask's Form in the html's parameters?

Tags: python, html, flask

I try with:

```
{{ form.theStringField(size=40) }}
```

Also try with:

```
class TheForm(FlaskForm):
    style={'style': 'width:200%; eight:900%;', 'readonly': True} # readonly para que no se pueda escribir dentro del StrinfField
    theSF = StringField('', validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw=style)
```

but that only change the width of the StringField, I can't move the eight...
Some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is setting "height", right? Passing the "height" attribute to flask StringField has no effect on rendering though "width" does. One tricky way to get around is setting "font-size".
Try following codes:

```
class TheForm(FlaskForm):
    style={'style': 'font-size: 36px', 'readonly': True} # The font-size depends on your requirement.
    theSF = StringField('', validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw=style)
```